# Pause until... or restart workflow

Tags: workflow, pause

Is there a preferred way to handle pause until workflows? I have a infopath form that has some basic approval process and I see I can pause until field changes or the workflow can simply end and restart on form update and check the field again at that time and proceed further into the workflow if the check passes.

For instance form is submitted and the form state (field) is set to WaitingApproval. The manager looks at the form decides to either pass it (approved) or ask for edits (editsrequired). I don't know the effect having lots and lots of paused workflows on the server so if it's best to just end the workflow then rerun it on form change/update I can certainly do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of a lot of paused workflows are almost non-existing. So you shouldn't worry about that.

But you should ALWAYS code your workflows such that they can be restarted on the same item and behave correctly (otherwise you won't be able to change them).

With that in  mind I'd suggest that in your scenario you just end your workflow unless you have a reason for them to stay alive. This reason could be that you want to send out a mail it nothing happens in X amount of time.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about restarts appreciate the reminder, thank you I will proceed as you suggest.